# iOS - Achievements not showing in default GameCenter view

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7, cocos2d-iphone, game-center

I have a really weird problem here. Currently, I'm using Cocos2D for my game, which has leaderboards and achievements. Everything works fine ; I can log in, send scores to leaderboards and complete achievements. There's only one thing that doesn't work : I can't get to show the achievements view.

What I want is, when the player opens Game Center in my app, to show the default 'dashboard' where you have the different leaderboards, with tabs at the top to go to the Achievements view. This is my current code :

```
- (void) showGameCenter{
    GKGameCenterViewController *gameCenterViewController = [[GKGameCenterViewController alloc] init];
    gameCenterViewController.gameCenterDelegate = self;
    gameCenterViewController.viewState = GKGameCenterViewControllerStateDefault;

    if (gameCenterViewController != NULL) {
        AppController *app = (AppController*) [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
        [[app navController] presentModalViewController:gameCenterViewController animated:YES];

        [gameCenterViewController release];
    }
}

- (void) gameCenterViewControllerDidFinish:(GKGameCenterViewController *)viewController{
    AppController *app = (AppController*) [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    [[app navController] dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

Strangely, on iPhone, the "Achievements" tab is never showing up at the top, but **IT IS** on iPad?!?! Everything is fine on iPad...

I also tried to change the `viewState` property of my gameCenterViewController to `GKGameCenterViewControllerStateAchievements` without any success. Also tried to use the `GKAchievementViewController` class instead of GKGameCenterViewController, still not working. It always sends me to the Leaderboards view...

I just can't figure out what's wrong. The weirdest thing is that everything **works fine on iPad**... Please help!

Thanks guys!

P.S My game is in Landscape Orientation and I'm currently testing on iOS 7.0.6 on my two devices

Comment: So... That's really weird, everything went back to normal just now... As I said below, I've sent a Support Ticket to Apple, I'll wait their answer and see if I can gather some juicy info to put them up here! I'll keep you in touch!

Comment: Hey, did you ever hear back from Apple about this? I am having a similar issue although with me everything worked 100% fine in development but doesn't show achievements in the live version on the app store.

Comment: I have similar issue. For all my devices with different iOS versions Game Center works fine, but on publisher's test device it doesn't work(

Comment: I have wierd problem. I am using " gameCenterController.viewState = GKGameCenterViewControllerStateAchievements;" but all the time it go leaderboard. problem is I made two button one goes to leaderboard and another achivements. but above mention line has no effect. :( any pointers would be appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

I just had this same exact problem and I stumbled upon this thread.  This is what worked for me:

1) Delete the app from your phone
2) Close simulator
3) Clean project (product > clean)
4) Go to Settings and log out of game center (also, make sure this is a sandbox account)
5) Restart iPhone
6) Build project in simulator (this is the stage where you should see achievements)
7) Now build on your test device and you should see achievements.

I'm not sure if this is the panacea for all, but it worked for me after messing around with code for an hour.  Hope it helps anyone else with this issue.

Comment: Had a similar issue: I wanted to see achievements, but I was getting the default leaderboard instead, for no reason. Just followed this steps and now it's working properly, with zero changes in the code. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I had the exact same problem as you describe when testing my app on iPhone and iPad simulators.
What made the achievement tab suddenly appear for me was when I quit/re-launched the iPhone simulator :)
Maybe resetting your physical iPhone could do the trick? Or even just signing out/in from Game Center?

Comment: Thank you for your tips, but unfortunately it didn't worked for me! :( But if you are telling me that it's a Game Center bug and it should be fine with my 'Release' version, then I won't reset my iPhone just for that! At least I can check my achievements on the official Game Center app! I'll wait until I get an answer from Apple's tech (I used one of my two tickets) and let you know if I get anything new. Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

I have found a solution, just use test users from https://itunesconnect.apple.com. Never use your real account.

Answer (score 1):

I am using GameCenter Achievements and it is working fine with iPhone and iPad in all ios Versions.
Let me write that code snippet here which might help you 
`GKAchievementViewController` is using in ios5 and `GKGameCenterViewController` has been introduced from ios6

```
- (void) showGameCenter{
if([[[UIDevice currentDevice]systemVersion]intValue]==5)
{
   GKAchievementViewController *achievements = [[GKAchievementViewController alloc] init];

   if (achievements != nil)
   {

    achievements.achievementDelegate = self;
    [self presentViewController: achievements animated: YES completion:nil];  
   }

   [achievements release];

}else if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice]systemVersion]intValue]>=6)
   {
     GKGameCenterViewController *gameCenterController = [[GKGameCenterViewController alloc] init];

     if (gameCenterController != nil)
      {

        gameCenterController.gameCenterDelegate = self;
        gameCenterController.viewState = GKGameCenterViewControllerStateAchievements;

        [self presentViewController: gameCenterController animated: YES completion:nil];

      }
    }
}   

- (void)achievementViewControllerDidFinish:(GKAchievementViewController *)viewController
{

       [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];


}

- (void)gameCenterViewControllerDidFinish:(GKGameCenterViewController *)gameCenterViewController
{

       [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

}
```

For more reference, see [Apple GameCenter Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/GameKit_Guide/Achievements/Achievements.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008304-CH7-SW13)

Comment: Thank you for your snippet, I used it to deal with lower iOS versions, but Achievements are still not showing. Even worse, today, when I go to Achievements in Game Center on my iPad, it says "No Achievements", just like if I don't have any on iTunes Connect... (That's not because of your code, but I don't know why!) Thanks anyway!

Comment: @UnluckyPotato : Are you using sandbox account or real account to login in game center? You may try logout from gamecenter and than open your app and login with test account and check it.

Comment: Already tried that, it didn't worked either. But now everything is back to normal, I guess it was only a Game Center bug! Like I said in my original post's comment, I'll wait an official answer from Apple before closing that question down! Thank you!